# Lambda expression check if null helper

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I want to be able to write

```
 MyObject.IsNull(p => p.MyObjectProperty)
```

I think it is achievable with expression.
I thied to implement it this way:

```
public static void IsNull<T>(this T root, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    if (CheckIfNull<T>(expression))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(GetName(expression));
    }
}

private static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
}

public static bool CheckIfNull<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    Expression<Func<T, object>> obj = o => expression.Compile().Invoke(o);
    return obj == null;
}
```

But it is seams to be not working.
How can I fix that?

Comment: you are comparing `obj` with `null` - which it never is, since one line above you are assigning a lambda-function to it. Instread check `obj(root) == null`. Other than that, **none** of your functions ever return `true` or `false` and they should not compile. Please check the code you provided

Comment: Please tell us what the behavior of `MyObject.IsNull(p => p.MyObjectProperty)` should be. It looks like you want an exception to be thrown if `MyObjectProperty` it is `null`, but then there is also the `bool` return value which is not ever used.

Comment: Just fixed the `bool` with `void`. Yes I want exception to be thorown in case `CheckIfNull<T>(expression) == true`

Comment: alright, now that that makes sense: did you ever try my answer? Does that fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have a bug:**

The comparison `obj == null` should be `obj(root) == null` - of course you have to pass `root` as an argument to `CheckIfNull`.

The former comparison will always evaluate to `false`, since you are effectively comparing `o => expression.Compile().Invoke(o)` with `null` - they are never equal. You rather want to compare the **result** of the call to `Invoke` with `null`.

**All my suggestions combined:**

```
public static bool CheckIfNull<T>(this T root, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    return expression.Compile()(root) == null;
}

public static void IsNull<T>(this T root, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    if (root.CheckIfNull<T>(expression))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(GetName(expression));
    }
}

private static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

Further comments:

- I'm not sure `ArgumentNullException` is the right exception for this situation. But without knowledge about your scenario, it is hard to suggest something better. Actually:
- it seems weird to write an extension method that merely throws an exception if a member is `null`, especially for a method named `IsNull`, which is why
- I would rename `IsNull` to `ThrowIfNull` and rename `CheckIfNull` to `IsNull`

Comment: just clerified my the question also initially I modify my code in notepad so I got it a bit wrong.

Comment: you are *still* comparing `obj == null` which will **always** be `false`! Also, you are *still* not returning a `bool` in `IsNull`.